# 70's/80's short story collection about space stories such as a moment by moment account of an astronaut going faster than light

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, hard-sci-fi

Short stories, may not have been in the same collection from the late 70’s/early 80’s.

1. A moment by moment account of an astronaut as he is the first to travel faster than light.  It described how everything slowed down to almost motionless.
2. Deep space station where 1 human is left waiting for the alien to come for trade.  Alien produces some product we need, side effect is the feeling of absolute dread and terror felt by the human.
3. Black and white planet visible from space has a very distinct black/white divide.  When they crash land, they determine the colors are made up by living creatures that cover the entire surface.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The first of those is probably [“Common Time”](https://apbsal.blogspot.com/2015/06/common-time-by-james-blish.html) by James Blish.

> Garrard travels around the speed of light to reach Alpha Centauri.
> However, instead of experiencing the same relativistic time as his
> ship, his own time passes about two hours for every second on the
> ship. Movement is impossible.

The second is almost certainly “Stranger Station” by Damon Knight.

> One man, out of all Sol’s billions, had the task and privilege of
> enduring the alien’s presence when it came. The two races, according
> to Wesson’s understanding of the subject, were so fundamentally
> different that it was painful for them to meet.

Cross-referencing on ISFDB, the anthology [*The Arbor House Treasury of Modern Science Fiction*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?35286), edited by Martin H Greenberg and Robert Silverberg and first published in 1980, contained both of those stories.

I can’t identify the third story as being in that anthology, but it could be [“Bordered in Black”](https://boards.straightdope.com/sdmb/archive/index.php/t-501122.html) by Larry Niven, which has not been widely anthologised.

> Two spacemen found a new planet. They observed the coastlines of all
> the continents were "bordered in black" (I think it was actually an
> infrared view). When they explored they found the planet had been
> artificially terraformed to act as a food producing planet. All the
> natural life had been exterminated and the oceans had been seeded with
> some algae that would be harvested for food. But the planet had been
> abandoned and the human-like caretakers had been forgotten and left
> behind. The black border was the descendants of the original
> caretakers who now crowded up against the beaches to get the algae
> which was the only food on the planet.

Comment: WOW! I am blown away. Thank you so much for the answers, you got them all.